# Natural topology on the algebraic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, metric-spaces, field-theory

My question has to do with the way we can construct $\mathbb{C}$ starting with the rationals.

The usual way: The reals are the analytic completion of the rationals, and thus inherit the appropriate topology.
We can define $\mathbb{C}$ as the algebraic closure of the reals, and it has dimension 2 over $\mathbb{R}$ so it can be given the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Alternatively: We could take the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of the rationals first. Is there a coordinate-free way of putting a metric/norm on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ such that the analytic completion of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is $\mathbb{C}$?

**Edit:** I understand that an absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ can be extended to any finite-dimensional extension, and I also understand that there may be multiple metrics on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ that yield equivalent topologies. But is there a canonical way in which such a metric may be obtained? I want to explicitly avoid methods that require us to write an algebraic number in the form $x + iy$, since that is choosing a privileged element $i$.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.math.uh.edu/~minru/valuation.pdf

Comment: Starting with the $p$-adic absolute value on $\mathbb Q$ we can extend to the algebraic numbers... this is quite different than what we get from $\mathbb C$.  And why would you say one is "natural" and the other not?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - @Peter the PDF shows ways to define an absolute value for a finite extension, but I don't see how to extend to the case of the algebraic closure.

Comment: @GEdgar I am not saying the $p$-adic absolute value is not natural, I am searching for a natural extension of the standard absolute value.

Comment: If you want the usual topology on $\mathbb{C}$ then you need the same sequences to converge, and they will then converge or at least be Cauchy in the algebraic numbers. Thus the algebraic numbers will have their usual topology. There are many metrics that will define this topology, eg $|z|=|x|+|y|$, or $|z|=max(|x|,|y|)$ both seem fairly natural to me.

Comment: @Peter when you say $|z| = |x| + |y|$, what are $x$ and $y$? Are you choosing $x$ and $y$ to be the real and imaginary part? I am specifically looking for something that avoids this, since this requires us to distinguish the algebraic element $i$ a priori.

Comment: If you are treating it as a 2d space you have implied you can find a basis of two vectors. Let x and y be the coordinates based on any such pair. I had real and complex in mind but for a F-norm (defining a metric) it doesn't matter.

Comment: The map $x+iy \mapsto x+\pi y$ is an injective map from algebraic complex numbers into $\mathbb R$.  Then $|x+\pi y|$ is a "norm" on the algebraic complex numbers. What if you use this distance on the algebraic complex numbers?  The basic concept here is: the norm on a finite-dimensional vector space over a valued field $F$ is unique only if $F$ is complete.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I think the answer has to be no. Consider the field $K=\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt{2})$. There are two independent absolute values on $K$ that have complex completions (there are two pairs of complex embeddings of $K$ which define two inequivalent absolute values and therefore different topologies). So there isn't even a co-ordinate free way to do this for $K$! In general, a metric on $\mathbb Q$ will extend to uncountably many inequivalent metrics on $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.